# Cannot compile nVidia HLSL sample - FXC Task does not support CommandLineTemplate

Tags: directx, gpu, nvidia, hlsl, directx-10

I'm trying to compile a sample from the nVidia website to do solid wireframe rendering:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/direct3d/samples.html

[image]

When I open the VC++ project in Visual Studio 2012 and compile, I receive this error message:

> Error 5   error MSB4064: The "CommandLineTemplate" parameter is not supported by the "FXC" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

[image]

Am I missing a framework or SDK? Or perhaps this sample needs to be modified to work with VS2012?

Many thanks!

Comment: How did you fix it? I have the same error, I've install DX SDK & link that library in the solution property, but I still can't fix that problem. I found the file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\bin\x86\fxc.exe", but I don't know what to do.

Comment: It was a long time ago so I've forgotten, but the answer below is related to installing DirectX SDK. Try the June 2010 DirectX SDK. It seems to be a common thread in DirectX / FXC dependency issues

Comment: Sorry, but how can I fix FXC dependency issue? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the latest [DX SDK installed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812)?

Also, is it possible that there is a custom compile action for VS to run FXC (shader compiler) that you are missing?

If you can find the parameters needed to compile their shaders via fxc, you can run it via the command prompt and is located in the bin folder of the DX SDK.

Comment: Hey jer, do I need DX SDK if I have VS2012 (which supposedly includes the DX SDK as part of the Windows 8 SDK?) FXC I will check out

Comment: VS2012 automatically assigns a custom build step to any HLSL/FX in the project, and tries to compile them when you build the project.

Comment: Hi, I have DirectX SDK (June 2010) installed. I'm trying to run this sample: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/direct3d/samples.html#SkinnedInstancing and have the same issue. I've tried adding DX SDK lib to: `Include Directories`, `Library Directories` in VS's Solution Property, but it doesn't help. I don't know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Also I notice that the file `FXC.targets` (which causes the error) is generated by VS after I run the file `SkinnedInstancing.vcproj` (VS 2015 upgraded the solution)